# Is there a built-in rake task like db:fixtures:load in factory_girl_rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a Rails 3 project with the following in my Gemfile...

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 1.1.beta1'
end
```

I also have several factory definitions in spec/factories.rb which my tests are using successfully. I would like to use these factories to populate my development database from time to time.

Is there anyway I can get Rail's db:fixtures:load rake task to load the factories defined in spec/factories.rb instead of the Yaml fixtures in test/fixtures? If not, is there another rake task in factory_girl_rails or Rails that would load the data generated by my factory definitions?

Pretty sure the best approach is to just write my own rake task to accomplish this but wanted to check here first.

Comment: an alternative way could be to make your `seeds` file load this for you. Just prepend the factories with `if Rails.env == "test"`

Comment: @apneadiving The if I would put in would be `if Rails.env == 'development'`. Also, I'd have to `&&` the if condition with something else that triggers the factory data to get loaded because I don't always want to load the factory data in development. The custom rake task probably sounds more feasible than a seeds.rb based solution. Thanks tho.

Comment: On second thought I'm going to go with @apneadiving's suggestion and just use seeds.rb because factories aren't really meant for this sort of thing. Wish I could reuse some of my factory code to generate this data but oh well.

Comment: Great. So I put the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way could be to make your `seeds.rb` file load this for you.

Just prepend the factories with `if Rails.env == "test"`